# Laravel 7: "Trying to get property of non-object" ¿Cómo resuelvo esto?

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, crud

Ya he estado buscando en otros hilos de este mismo foro y por internet en general y no encuentro una solución para mi situación en concreto.

Lo que sucede es que a la mínima que añado un dato nuevo a mi base de datos a través de mis crud, salta este error cuando intento acceder de nuevo a mi página principal de home (home.blade.php). Home sí va bien antes de lo de añadir algo nuevo, pero después de esto salta este error y no sé qué tengo que hacer.

Añado capturas (marcando en rojo los sitios a los que se puede acceder para interactuar con mis crud) y el código de mi home.blade.php porque me supongo que es ahí donde está el kit del problema, ya que mis crud en sí sí van bien.

```
<head>
    <title>Adrián Pérez: Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body class="bg-secondary">
    <header class="w-100 bg-dark">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <a href="/" class="text-decoration-none"><img src="{{asset('img/logo1.jpg')}}" alt="" width="75" height="75"></img></a>
            <a href="/" class="text-decoration-none text-white"><h1>Aula Campus</h1></a>
        </div>
    </header>
    </br>
    <div class="d-flex">
        <aside class="bg-dark w-25">
            <nav>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="/roles" class="font-weight-bold text-white text-decoration-none"><h4>Roles</h4></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/users" class="font-weight-bold text-white text-decoration-none"><h4>Usuarios</h4></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/posts" class="font-weight-bold text-white text-decoration-none"><h4>Posts</h4></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/comments" class="font-weight-bold text-white text-decoration-none"><h4>Comentarios</h4></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/attachments" class="font-weight-bold text-white text-decoration-none"><h4>Adjuntos</h4></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </aside>
        <main class="bg-light w-75">
            </br>
            <div class="bg-white d-block mx-auto w-75">
                <a href="/posts" class="text-center w-100 btn btn-outline-primary">Publicar</a>
            </div>
            </br>
            @foreach($posts as $post)
                <div class="w-75 mx-auto d-block bg-white">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <img src="{{asset('img/userIcon.png')}}" alt="" width="35" height="35"></img>
                        <p class="font-weight-bold">{{$post->user->first_name}} {{$post->user->last_name}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <p>{{$post->updated_at}}</p>
                    <h3 class="text-center">{{$post->title}}</h3>
                    </br>
                    <div class="border-bottom">
                        <img src="{{asset('img/dinantia.jpg')}}" alt="" class="d-block mx-auto border"></img>
                        </br>
                        <p class="text-justify d-block mx-auto">{{$post->text}}</p>
                    </div>
                    </br>
                    <div>
                        <div class="float-left">
                            <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none text-danger">
                                <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-heart-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 1.314C12.438-3.248 23.534 4.735 8 15-7.534 4.736 3.562-3.248 8 1.314z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <p class="float-right">{{count($comments)}} Comentarios</p>
                    </div>
                    </br>
                    </br>
                    @foreach($comments as $comment)
                        <div class="d-flex">
                            <img src="{{asset('img/userIcon.png')}}" alt="" width="35" height="35"></img>
                            <div class="bg-light w-75">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">{{$comment->user->first_name}} {{$comment->user->last_name}}</p>
                                <p>{{$comment->text}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </br>
                    @endforeach
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <form method="post" action="{{route('comments.store')}}">
                            @csrf
                            <label for="text"></label>
                            <input type="text" name="text"/>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Enviar</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </br>
            @endforeach
        </main>
    </div>
    </br>
    <footer class="bg-primary w-100">
        <div class="text-center text-white">
            <p>Adrián Pérez</p>
            <p>11 de julio de 2020</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el error en cuestión:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HomeController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\Comment;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        $comments = Comment::all();

        foreach($posts as $post) {
            $post->user = $post->user;
            $post->comments = $post->comments;
        }

        foreach($comments as $comment) {
            $comment->user = $comment->user;
        }

        return view('home', compact('posts', 'comments'));
    }
```

Modelo de Comment (Comment.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Post;

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'comments';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'user_id',
        'post_id',
        'text'
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function post() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo que dice el error es que `$comment->user` no es un objeto y por tanto no puedes acceder a su propiedad `first_name`
. No uso Laravel, pero, debes revisar en tu modelo de datos si realmente existe un objeto de ese tipo y si lo está mapeando bien en ese contexto. Podrías depurar con algo como `var_dump($comment);` o mediante el comando de depuración de Laravel. Así verás cómo está constituido ese objeto, si es nulo, etc.

Comment: Enséñanos como coges los comentarios en php.

Comment: @pwron, ya te he subido un código a ver si eso sirve.

Comment: @Adrijo si eso es lo que quería, lo primero cuando alguien te pida que añadas algo, no lo añadas en una respuesta, edita tu pregunta y evita pegar código innecesario. respecto al código añadido, esos foreach no tienen ningún sentido a priori. Pegame el código del modelo Comment.

Comment: @Adrijo añademe tb el código del modelo Comment y vemos la relación que tienes realizada entre user y comment

Comment: @Adrijo las relaciones parecen correctas, prueba a hacer un `dd($comments);` justo despues de `$comments = Comment::with('user')->get();` y peganos el resultado.

Comment: @Adrijo de todos modos prueba a quitar esos foreach del controlador y prueba, ya que no son necesarios.